# docker-compose up fails for running network_mode=host services

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

For a network_mode: host service,

```
version: '2'
 services:
  redis:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.0-debian-10'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - REDIS_DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB,FLUSHALL
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - 'redis_data:/bitnami/redis/data'
  demo:
    image: demo
    container_name: "demo"
    network_mode: host
    command: bash -c "cd /sample/ ; python manage.py makemigrations --noinput ;  python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb; python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:demo --noreload"
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

I am using redis image for django channels functionality but when i do docker-compose up i am getting below error

```
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

If i remove `network_mode: host` from docker-compose , i am not getting any error and i could successfully make container up and running

i have to add `network_mode: host` in docker-compose for project specific dependency how can i successfully make redis server up and running with `network_mode: host`, Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Specifying host networking disables most of the standard Docker functionality, including inter-container communications; it's rarely actually necessary.  What's the "project-specific dependency" where you think you need it?

Comment: In a bridge network setup where we have connected and configured usb network adapter, we are accessing network adapter interface of host machine inside container

Comment: Is there any workaround ?

Comment: What does "accessing" mean here?  You shouldn't need to do anything special to make outbound connections or receive inbound connections through that interface.

Comment: upgrade your docker-compose YAML version to '3' instead of '2'

Comment: auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eno1 inet manual
iface enx00e04c534458 inet manual
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eno1 enx00e04c534458 i was accessing enx00e04c534458 inside container without using network_mode : host it was not listing inside container, hence added